# Page is getting rendered in firefox safe-mode but not in normal mode

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-7

I have a page which gets rendered if I open it in firefox safe-mode and browser gets crashed if I open it in normal mode (browser error message says "some problem occurred and dump doesn't have any information). I does work well in the chrome but it crashes again in the IE7. 
I assume that nothing wrong in the backend code as its going through fine in the chrome and firefox safe-mode. What could potentially be the problem?
Any guesses? Its an UIX page being rendered by ADF.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any add in in firefox? Try on a fresh install ?

Comment: its failing in the IE7 also - which doesn't have any addons